# Java String Input error

Tags: java, string, loops, java.util.scanner

So this question is kinda simple, but I was wondering why the following code, after running perfectly the first time, jumps straight to "Enter the page number: ", instead of asking for the title the second loop around. I've read somewhere that there is something up with Java that won't allow for a reuse of a Scanner. Is this the problem that I'm facing? I've tried to use kbReader.next() and that works, but the code only works with strings without spaces.

```
String title = "";
int page = 0;
int i = 0;
Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);

for (i=1;i<=3;i++){
        System.out.print("Enter the title: ");
        title = kbReader.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the page number: ");
        page = kbReader.nextInt();

        System.out.print(title);
        System.out.println(page);
    }
```

Much help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a `kbReader.nextLine();` after `kbReader.nextInt();`. On the second loop, your `kbReader.nextInt();` is just reading the end-of-line in the stream, left out by `kbReader.nextInt();`.